# New easylist item with enter in VS Code

Tags: vscode, easylist

I am new to LaTeX and I started using the easylist package because I find it very convenient. However, it is still a bit annoying that I am unable to create a new list entry by pressing the enter key. In comparison with normal itemize lists, I can press Enter in VS Code to create a new \item, while this does not work with the # signs I use for easylist.
Does anyone here have an idea how I can configure VS Code to achieve this?
I would be very happy if someone here could help me :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I don't know how easy it is to modify the code completion/suggestion functionality of VSCode but I would be surprised if it was possible (of course I like being surprised, so I hope you get an answer). However, the whole idea of easylist is that it is easy to type list items or add levels, just two or maybe 3-4 keystrokes which you can learn to do manually without thinking about it :)